# PySpark: Performing same operation, multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm quite new to Spark/PySpark and have been trying to remain consistent in following 'best practices' but unfortunately, sometimes I revert to hacky solutions like below.

I am working on a tweet dataset which contains base tweets, retweeted content, and quoted content. If the tweet is not a retweeted_status or quoted_status, each subfeature for this is set to None or an empty list or some other variant depending on datatype.

What I am trying to do is to create new columns for each of these features, using the content from either the base feature IF it is not a retweet or quoted status, OR to use the retweeted content, OR to use the base feature + the quoted content.

```
def _shared_content(feature, df):
    return df.withColumn(f'tweet_{feature.replace("entities.", "")}',
        when((col(f'`retweeted_status.{feature}`').isNotNull()),
              df[f'`retweeted_status.{feature}`'])
        .when((col(f'`quoted_status.{feature}`').isNotNull()),
                concat(
                       df[f'`{feature}`'],
                       lit(" "),
                       df[f'`quoted_status.{feature}`']))
        .otherwise(df[f'`{feature}`']))

common_features = [
    'text',
    'entities.hashtags',
    'entities.media',
    'entities.urls',
]

for f in common_features:
    df = df.transform(lambda df, f=f: _shared_content(f, df))
```

As you can see this is a bit of a mess so I've written a bit of pseudo-code for legibility. Here I am carrying out the following functions:

- For each feature in common features:

  - If retweet_status.[FEATURE] is not None, set new col tweet_[FEATURE] to retweet_status.[FEATURE]
  - If quoted_status.[FEATURE] is not None, set new col tweet_[FEATURE] to [FEATURE] + " " + quoted_status.[FEATURE]
  - Otherwise, set tweet_[FEATURE] to base [FEATURE].

This solution currently works but feels awfully hacky and frankly illegible. I was wondering if there was a more Spark-like approach to this, where I could eliminate a lot of the redundant code? I tried to apply some sort of mapping from the list to the function but got a little lost.

As a final clarification, I am performing the same transformation but the only thing that changes is the feature I'm working on.

**EDIT:** I've made this *slightly* more legible with:

```
def _shared_content(f, df):
    new_col = f'tweet_{f.replace("entities.", "")}'

    retweet_cond = ((
        col(f'`retweeted_status.{f}`').isNotNull()),
                    df[f'`retweeted_status.{f}`'])
    quoted_cond = ((
        col(f'`quoted_status.{f}`').isNotNull()),
                   concat(df[f'`{f}`'], lit(" "), df[f'`quoted_status.{f}`']))

    return df.withColumn(
        new_col,
        when(*retweet_cond)
        .when(*quoted_cond)
        .otherwise(df[f'`{f}`'])
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write something like this:

```
def _shared_content(feature, df):
    feat_col = col(feature)
    retweet = col(f"retweeted_status.{feature}")
    quoted = col(f"quoted_status.{feature}")
    new_feat_name = f'tweet_{feature.replace("entities.", "")}'

    return df.withColumn(
        new_feat_name,
        (
            when(retweet.isNotNull(), retweet)
            .when(quoted.isNotNull(), concat(feat_col, lit(" "), quoted))
            .otherwise(feat_col)
        ),
    )
```

Some principles that I usually follow when writing code with Pyspark (or anything else):

- Avoid code duplication (you've repeated column names in multiple places)
- Replace raw values by variable names when it helps readability (as in the case of the new feature name)
- Use Spark column objects instead of unnecessarily reference the same DataFrame with `df["<column name>"]`.

PS.: I'm not sure why you are using backquotes.

Comment: Hi there, thanks very much. I've tried your improvements and looks a lot better already. However, the same functionality doesn't seem to work when I use Spark column objects in place of df['col'], it ends up seemingly breaking my columns? Also backquotes are to escape the period in the column title as some are named 'entities.hashtags' and are PySpark interprets them as nested.

Comment: Update: Apologies, you were right! I just wasn't escaping properly when defining my variables, thanks for the help.